# onCreate not being called in debug build?

Tags: android, oncreate, onresume

I found my app behavior differently between debug build vs release build:

In debug, when re-open the app after home button is pressed, onResume is called. (onCreate is NOT called).

In production (release build), re-open the app calls onCreate first when home button is pressed.

The difference introduces a bug because I set a flag in onCreate.  Question: which one is the right behavior?  Am I able to make my release build work the same way as the debug build (without onCreate being called when re-open the app after home button is pressed)?

Comment: forgive my poor english -(  do you mean you don't understand what my question, or either the debug or release build behavior just doesn't make sense?

Comment: The behaviour for destroying activities (needing to call onCreate) is dependent in the OS not the application

Comment: You can also override onDestroy and onRestart if it helps

Comment: Thanks Marcos!.  Would you please elaborate override onDestroy(), or onRestart()?

Answer (score 1):

> In debug, when re-open the app after home button is pressed, onResume
>   is called. (onCreate is NOT called).

- that is perfectly correct behavior!

Settings -> Developer Options -> aplication section.
"Do not keep activities" - default is off.

I suspect "**when re-open the app after home button is pressed**" your activity is in background only and normally shouldn't be destroyed, hence shouldn't have called the onCreate. So the debug mode is working as expected.

In release mode you have something which kills your activity, when is he in a background. Can be a part of the code, can be a missing translation or an unhanded exception somewhere, you should get an ANR or "aplication exited unexpectedly"

I would suggest to try some logs int a file or and check what happens the in release mode.

Can be another app - even from Android OS -, which detect your application went to background so it will kill it to make more room in memory, but he doesn't kill the Debug apps..

Comment: Thanks!  I feel this is the right direction for me to look for the culprit code that suggest the OS terminate the app in background: I logcat the onDestroy() when pressing the home key, it doesn't get called, however onCreate() get called when re-open it.  One thing for sure just learned, the business rule is implemented relying on this event, that is not good.